# Java - JWebBrowser не обновляет страницу

Tags: java, json, swing, webbrowser

Добавил в фрейм [JWebBrowser](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html). В браузер кидаю локальный html-файл, в котором js-скрипт с яндекс-картой, который подгружает json файл с координатами точек, чтобы их поставить на карту, через:

```
webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
final JPanel webPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
webPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
webBrowser.navigate(WebServer.getDefaultWebServer()
          .getClassPathResourceURL(getClass().getName(), "index.html"));
```

Создал также кнопку для обновления json-файла с координатами точек и записью туда новых точек. Проблема заключается в том, что браузер обновляет только html-страницу с js-скриптом, при этом координаты точек остаются старыми и показываются старые точки, хотя json файл изменен и там лежат уже новые точки. Если закрыть программу и открыть, то все ок - на карте отмечены уже новые точки. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку обновлялась не только html-страница, но и вызываемый из нее json-файл, чтобы считывались новые точки?

Пробовал обновлять страницу как через:

```
webBrowser.reloadPage();
```

так и через удаление webBrowser компоненты и создание новой, все бесполезно.

```
                webBrowser.disposeNativePeer();
                webPanel.removeAll();
                webPanel.revalidate();
                webPanel.repaint();

                webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
                webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
                webBrowser.navigate(WebServer.getDefaultWebServer().
                        getClassPathResourceURL(getClass().getName(), "index.html"));
                webPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                webPanel.revalidate();
                webPanel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решается убиванием WebServer'a через

```
WebServer.stopDefaultWebServer();
```

Нет смысла убивает webBrowser и создавать снова, вот, оказывается, более удобный код (вдруг пригодится кому-нибудь):

```
WebServer.stopDefaultWebServer();
WebServer.getDefaultWebServer();
webBrowser.navigate(WebServer.getDefaultWebServer()
                            .getClassPathResourceURL(getClass().getName(), "index"));
```